# Can i test all assertions of a test after the first assertion failed?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have a list of different audioformats, to which a certain file should be converted. The conversion function i have written, should now convert the file and return information on success, the path to the newly created file or some failure information.

```
self.AUDIO_FORMATS = ({'format':'wav', 'samplerate':44100, 'bitdepth':16 },
                      {'format':'aac', 'samplerate':44100, 'bitdepth':16 },
                      {'format':'ogg', 'samplerate':44100, 'bitdepth':16 },
                      {'format':'mp3', 'samplerate':44100, 'bitdepth':16 } )
```

As one possible reason for one of the conversions failing is a missing library, or some bug or failure in such a library or my implementation of it, i want to test each of the conversions to have a list of passed and failed tests in the end, where the failed ones tell me exactly which conversion did cause the trouble. This is what i tried (a bit simplified):

```
def test_convert_to_formats(self):

    for options in self.AUDIO_FORMATS:
        created_file_path, errors = convert_audiofile(self.audiofile,options)
        self.assertFalse( errors )
        self.assertTrue( os.path.isfile(created_file_path),
```

Now this is, of course, aborting the test as soon as the first conversion fails. I could write a test function for each of the conversions. That would result in having to write a new test for each added format, where now i just have to add a new dictionary to my AUDIO_FORMATS tuple.

Comment: Your unit test should only test a single focused scenario. Yes, in your case it is converting to a specific format. However, you have a specific scenario for each format. Your test should only test the convertion for a specific format. This does not mean you have to write multiple tests, one for each format. You can have a method loop through the formats and for each format call your test method passing the specific format. That way you are making sure that a test failing for converting 1 format does not impact the test for another and also no need to hack up the asserts into an array,etc.

Comment: @Francois: that sounds almost exactly like what i intended to do. I just couldn't get that to work inside a TestCase. Could you provide an example on how you would code that? (I'll update my question accordingly)

Comment: I'm coming from a .Net background. I don't know python and would not be able to give you the syntax for that. That's also why I only added a comment, trying direct to a more structured possible way of executing your test. In .NET the test frameworks allow you to add an attribute above your test method specifying the different sets of parameters you want to pass for each time you call the test. Works well for situations like yours. Sadly I don't know how I would do that implementation in python. If python is restricted `Ates Goral`'s solution might be the only way.

Comment: @Francois: I think that would be my real question then: (How) can i run a test in Python with different parameter sets? I'm going to stick with Ates' solution meanwhile, but that question will probably shortly be asked on SO ;) Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I wasn't able to give a code sample. That's why I kept it in comments :) However the idiology of unit testing is the same and it would be cool if you can find a solution to call your test several times instead with the different sets fo required params. At least you have something working for now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of asserting, store the errors in an array. At the end of your iteration, assert that the errors array is empty and potentially dump the contents of the array as the assertion failure reason.

Answer (score 0):

why not use  **try...except...** ?

```
  errors = []

  for option in optionlist:
    try:
      assert_and_raise1(option)
      assert_and_raise2(...)
    except Exception, e:
      errors.append("[%s] fail: %s"%(option, e))

   for e in errors:
     print e
```

Comment: This is almost the same as what Ates Goral proposed. If i just don't do an assertion, i don't have to catch exceptions. So when i decide to collect the errors, i'll stick with Ates solution. Thanks anyway.